A function returning anonymous structure
Why is the following construct invalid:
struct { int a, b; float c; } func ()
{
    struct { int a, b; float c; } test;
    
    return test;
    //return (struct { int a, b; float c; }){0,0,0.0}; /* same with designated initializer */
}

It doesn't compile with GCC, with this nonsensical error:

error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct ’ but ‘struct ’
was expected


warning: control reaches end of non-void function


Why is using a non-anonymous struct twice not an option? Is unreadability a requirement? E.g. for obfuscation purposes?

@Yunnosch I am designing a complete C interpreter :)

Does not seem like a reason.

@Yunnosch It is likely the best reason. It is an implementation detail that I need to consider. I am promising GNU C99-compatibility as closest as possible. I have the option to make this a valid declaration/definition. Or not.

Weren't anonymous structs only introduced in C11?

typeof(func()) test; would work in C23.

For starters there are no anonymous structures in the presented code. There are unnamed structures without tag names.
According to the C Standard

13 An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier
with no tag is called an anonymous structure; an unnamed member
whose type specifier is a union specifier with no tag is called an
anonymous union. The members of an anonymous structure or union are
considered to be members of the containing structure or union, keeping
their structure or union layout. This applies recursively if the
containing structure or union is also anonymous.

That is an anonymous structure can be represented only as a member of a structure or union.
You declared two unnamed structures in different scopes: one in the file scope and other in the function block scope. The declaration of the structure in the function block scope hides the declaration of the structure in the file scope. So they are two different types and the compiler says that they are not compatible.

Would it be a feature if unnamed structures with the exact same members are compatible, or a bug? In other words, what is the reason behind this design choice? It is much easier to implement the way it is.

@Edenia Here is a problem with the compatibility at least because the structures are declared in different scopes.

It throws the error even if I directly assign objects of the same unnamed structure type in the same scope. Also why would the scope matter? Is there a reason behind them not be seen as compatible? I am trying to understand wether it would be beneficial if unnamed structures with the same members-list are made compatible and whether that has its own set of implications.

@Edenia It seems for unnamed structures the compiler internally assigns different tag names. The C Standard should elaborate such a situation.

Ah, that is an interesting and important to me detail. I guess I will do the same thing. Maybe I've seen automatically-assigned names such as __unnamed_34 or something like that. But does that mean that I can refer to an unnamed structure using the compiler-given tag, whatever it is?

@Edenia  The compatfibility of structures makes sense for arguments of function calls.

Passed it as an argument it throws a warning "anonymous struct declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration"... and it uses the term "anonymous"

@Edenia An unnamed structure does not have external linkage if only it is not used in a typedef declaration that declares an alias name. You may not refer such a generated name.

@Edenia An unnamed structure declared in a parameter ltype ist is not visible outside the function declaration.

So as far as I understand, the internally-assigned tags have the sole purpose of making the compiler able to distinguish between the unnamed structures and diagnose all operations that involve the movl-ing of the structures one into another.

Each instance of struct { struct-declaration-list } defines a new type, per C 2018 6.7.2.1 8:

The presence of a struct-declaration-list in a struct-or-union-specifier declares a new type, within a translation unit…

One reason for this is we might want to use two structures with the same types of contents for different purposes. For example, a structure type with two float members could be used for a point in a plane, while another structure type with two float members could be used for a complex number.
Since the declaration of func and the declaration of test each have their own structure definition, they are different types. Different structure types are incompatible.1 And that is why the compiler issues the error on the return statement.
To fix this, give the structure type a name, as with:
typedef struct { int a, b; float c; } MyType;

MyType func(void)
{
    MyType test = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return test;
}

or give the structure a tag:
struct MyTag { int a, b; float c; } func(void)
{
    struct MyTag test = { 0, 1, 2 };
    return test;
}

Footnote
1 There is no specific rule in the C standard for this. Types are compatible if there is a rule in the standard that says they are compatible. No rule says that different structure types in one translation unit, even identically defined types, are compatible. Structure types defined in different translation units with identical tags (or lack thereof) and members are identical.

Ahh, shame the compiler isn't smart enough to see them as compatible :)

@Edenia: It is not a matter of smart enough. It would be fairly simple to modify a compiler to treat the types as identical. This is a rule of the C standard, deliberately chosen.

I meant from a purely practical standpoint I would prefer an exception that allows this to happen. So anonymous structures can only be passed between functions as pointers.
